# Why does the canvas context.fill(path) not work on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, canvas, path, fill

This code would have worked on Chrome until recently.

```
    var canvasB=document.getElementById('b');
    var contextB=canvasB.getContext("2d");
    contextB.width=50;
    contextB.height=50;
    contextB.beginPath();
    contextB.fillStyle="#0A0";
    contextB.fill(contextB.arc(25,25,24,0,7,0));
```

Notice within the fill method the path is specified to draw a circle. According to [whatwg.org](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#fill-and-stroke-styles) this is acceptable. The solution to put the path on it own line and just use fill() without any arguments.

```
    var canvasA=document.getElementById('a');
    var contextA=canvasA.getContext("2d");
    contextA.width=50;
    contextA.height=50;
    contextA.beginPath();
    contextA.fillStyle="#0A0";
    contextA.arc(25,25,24,0,7,0);
    contextA.fill();
```

Still why did this stop working or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fill(Path) argument is not (yet) supported on any released browser.

It *should* have never worked. That Path stuff in the WHATWG spec is new as of March 2013 and no browser has implemented the independent Paths yet.

It's possible (but unlikely) that a mistaken development implementation made that feature possible for a short while, but it does not work right now, even on nightly. You'll get the appropriate type error instead.